# Sonata admin custom list action calls wrong method

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

As the name suggests, sonata admin custom list actions calls the wrong method.

There are two admin classes

- AppleIdAdmin
- ITunesGiftCardAdmin

there are two other controllers:

- PrintController
- SMSController

each admin classes are able to send sms and print the object using two different methods created in each controller,

- smsAppleIdAction
- smsITunesAction
- printAppleIdAction
- printITunesAction

here is my `service.yml`:

```
services:
    administration_product_product.admin.apple_id:
        class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\AppleIdAdmin
        arguments: [~, Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\AppleId, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Gift Cards, label: Apple ID}

    administration_product_product.admin.sms_appleid:
        class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\AppleIdAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Apple ID }
        arguments:
            - null
            - Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\AppleId
            - AdministrationProductProductBundle:SMS

    administration_product_product.admin.print_appleid:
        class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\AppleIdAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Apple ID }
        arguments:
            - null
            - Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\AppleId
            - AdministrationProductProductBundle:Print

    administration_product_product.admin.i_tunes_gift_card:
        class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\ITunesGiftCardAdmin
        arguments: [~, Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\ITunesGiftCard, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Gift Cards, label: iTunes Gift Card }

    administration_product_product.admin.print_itunes:
        class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\ITunesGiftCardAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: iTunes Gift Card }
        arguments:
            - null
            - Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\ITunesGiftCard
            - AdministrationProductProductBundle:Print
administration_product_product.admin.sms_itunes:
    class: Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Admin\ITunesGiftCardAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: iTunes Gift Card }
    arguments:
        - null
        - Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Entity\ITunesGiftCard
        - AdministrationProductProductBundle:SMS
```

The weird thing is that, when sending apple id via sms (printing is ok!) i'm getting this error:

```
Controller "Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Controller\PrintController::smsAppleIdAction" for URI "/admin/product/product/appleid/smsAppleId" is not callable.
```

and when printing iTunes card (sms is ok!) this error shows:

```
Controller "Administration\Product\ProductBundle\Controller\SMSController::printITunesAction" for URI "/admin/product/product/itunesgiftcard/printITunes" is not callable.
```

Also all list_action twig files are ok and they call the correct action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was to use a controller for each admin, and use sms and print method in this controller.
Don't know why, but it could help someone... one day :)

so now, I have `AppleIdContoller`, `ITunesContoller`, and each of these controller contain the appropriate `smsAction` and `printAction`